# How to filter traffic from Google Maps/local searches in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Can you filter in Google Analytics the traffic that originates from the local searches as seen in the image below?

[image: local search results in google]

*EDIT: Added an image of the search results that I want to track separately.*

Comment: You can read more about it here: http://localu.org/blog/how-to-segment-local-search-analytics/ Also, heres an actual Google Analytics template for tracking local data etc: https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=gNhA6alsRsy9rFxKJSz2Ng

Comment: Thank you. If I'm using this template correctly, it isn't showing a separate segment for the search results in this example: http://imgur.com/raT3Rth . How would you track these results separately?

Comment: so right now on google analytics, where is the local search traffic being recorded? Is it just part of the seo traffic or is it not being reported at all?

Answer (score 1):

About 6 months ago, I was looking into this and I used a tool to record HTTP headers and realized that visits from local listings on Google (at least if the 'visit website' link for a business in a SERP is clicked) do not send referrer data.

One place that you can see that data is in AdWords under the 'Dimensions' tab.

I almost always link AdWords to Analytics & Webmaster Tools so I'm not completely certain if that report is available if the accounts aren't linked.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have added my Webmaster Tools account to Adwords and I will report back in a few days after their is some data to test with. In which view of the dimension tab is this data available?

Comment: The report you'll look for under the dimensions tab is 'Free Clicks'

Answer (score 1):

You can add UTM parameters for Google Analytics into your website URLs in Google My Business.

To help you get there, using the campaign tags you can use the Store name or ID to filter your traffic in Google Analytics from Maps Results.